# JavaFX TabPane switch tabs only when focused

Tags: java, javafx

I need to switch tabs on **Ctrl-Tab** and **Ctrl-Shift-Tab**. But it works only when **TabPane is in focus**. I have Tabs with setContent(textArea).
When **textArea** is in focus, and I press **Ctrl-Tab**, focus goes somewhere in menu:

```
    TextArea@3f40a15a[styleClass=text-input text-area]
    TextArea@7b7c82a4[styleClass=text-input text-area]
    TabPane[id=null, styleClass=tab-pane]
    TextArea[id=null, styleClass=text-input text-area]
    MenuButtonSkinBase$MenuLabeledImpl[id=null, styleClass=label]
    TextArea[id=null, styleClass=text-input text-area]
    MenuButtonSkinBase$MenuLabeledImpl[id=null, styleClass=label]
    TextArea[id=null, styleClass=text-input text-area]
    TabPane[id=null, styleClass=tab-pane]
    TextArea[id=null, styleClass=text-input text-area]
    MenuButtonSkinBase$MenuLabeledImpl[id=null, styleClass=label]
    TextArea[id=null, styleClass=text-input text-area]
```

I track focus changes like this:

```
    scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> ov, Node t, Node t1) {
            System.out.println(t1);
        }
    });
```

I have **setFocusTraversable** to **false** almost on every component(including menu, toolbar, textArea and panes)

I created Tabs and used **setContent(textArea)**.

Also I want to **requestFocus** on textArea every time user open/close tab and switch between tabs(using mouse and keyboard hotkeys).

```
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (tabPane.getTabs().size() > 0) {
                        FileTab tab = (FileTab)tabPane.getTabs().get(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
                        tab.getTextArea().requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

This does not work.
I tried **tab.getContent().requestFocus()** - doesn't work too.

About changing tabs when TabPane child is in focus:
It seems like TabPane gets KeyEvent, but because it's not in focus(textArea in focus), it just skips this event.
Maybe I could duplicate default functionality by firing **KeyEvent** at **TabPane** or maybe even re implement it on my own. Or maybe I could call nextTab/previousTab default actions from this listener:

tabPane.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler() {

```
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB) && t.isControlDown()) {
                  //Event.fireEvent(tabPane, event); //I'm not sure how to do it like this
                  //Maybe it's better to just call default actions on TabPane.
                  t.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

http://s23.postimg.org/poeujzwbf/screenshot_185.png

But I still don't know how to set focus on **TextArea** after tab switch.
Maybe I should try to call **Platform.runLater()** after some delay?

Comment: Can you [filter the event on the scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addEventFilter(javafx.event.EventType,%20javafx.event.EventHandler)) rather than the TabPane?

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I thought that JavaFX has more elegant solution. Anyway I got it working, but still don't know to set focus on TextArea inside Tab after tab switch, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work(requestFocus()).

Comment: @AS3Boyan, can you try put only `tab.getTextArea().requestFocus();` in Platform.runLater, namely put the if-statement out of it. Alternatively use timeline to request the focus after 100ms for instance.

Comment: @Uluk Biy, I thought about running after delay, I wonder if in Java 8 those things fixed. new Timer() seems like works fine, but Application does not terminate properly. I will try to use Timeline, if you have example on how to use it as timer, please let me know.

Comment: @AS3Boyan, see [(http://stackoverflow.com/a/16920898](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16920898) and [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9966213](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9966213).

Comment: @UlukBiy, I tried using Timer, but without timer.cancel();                              timer.purge(); function call, app just doesn't terminate properly. (With Platform.runLater() inside run() function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOR TABS SWITCH:**

```
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB) && t.isControlDown()) {
                int size = tabPane.getTabs().size();

                if (size > 0) {
                    SkinBase skin = (SkinBase) tabPane.getSkin();
                    TabPaneBehavior tabPaneBehavior = (TabPaneBehavior) skin.getBehavior();

                    int selectedIndex = tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

                    if (!t.isShiftDown()) {
                        if (selectedIndex < size -1) {
                            tabPaneBehavior.selectNextTab();
                        } else {
                            tabPaneBehavior.selectTab(tabPane.getTabs().get(0));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (selectedIndex > 0) {
                            tabPaneBehavior.selectPreviousTab();
                        } else {
                            tabPaneBehavior.selectTab(tabPane.getTabs().get(size - 1));
                        }
                    }

                    t.consume();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

**SOLUTION FOR SETTING FOCUS ON SELECTED TAB:**

```
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, final Number t1) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (tabPane.getTabs().size() > 0) {
                        final FileTab tab = (FileTab) tabPane.getTabs().get(t1.intValue());

                        final Timer timer = new Timer();
                        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        tab.getContent().requestFocus();
                                        timer.cancel();
                                        timer.purge();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 25);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION FOR SETTING FOCUS ON SELECTED TAB(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920898 by @Uluk Biy):**

```
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, final Number t1) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (tabPane.getTabs().size() > 0) {
                        final FileTab tab = (FileTab) tabPane.getTabs().get(t1.intValue());

                        final Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(25),
                                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                tab.getContent().requestFocus();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }));
                        animation.setCycleCount(1);
                        animation.play();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

This should be better solution than just using timer.

Comment: There is no need to wrap code inside of `KeyFrame` handler in `Platform.runlater(...)`

Comment: I am using JDK 8u162, I tested this code and it's working in my project: `getTabs().forEach(e -> e.setOnSelectionChanged(o -> Platform.runLater(() -> e.getContent().requestFocus())));`. Perhaps it will work on yours too.

Comment: In my above solution, if user clicks again on the `Tab`, its content will lose focus. Use this code on the `TabPane` to make sure subsequent clicks on the `Tab` or clicks on the space in the tab bar will keep focus on its content: `setOnMousePressed(e -> getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent().requestFocus());`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following to focus the first tab (i.e. tab 0) :

```
Platform.runLater(() -> tabPane.getTabs().get(0).getContent().requestFocus());
```